# How do I get the data points to go to the ends of the plot in Echarts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, echarts

I am trying to create a chart but for some reason I cannot get the data points to go to the end of the chart except by clicking on the line chart tool button.

I stripped everything off the chart and still it did it.  I have a number of different fields in the xAxis options and still it won't push to the ends.

This is what I am getting -
[Picture of the chart not going to the ends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29uyF.png)

This is what I am looking for - [Picture of what I am trying to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nAtC.png)

It looks like it something due to where it is placing the label in regards to the tick, but everything I have tried hasn't work.

Here is my component -

```
function MoraleLineChart({ data, colors }) {
  const barOptions = {
    tooltip: {
      trigger: "axis",
      axisPointer: {
        type: "shadow",
      },
    },
    legend: {},
    grid: {
      left: "5%", // Set left padding
      right: "10%", // Set right padding
    },
    toolbox: {
      show: true,
      orient: "vertical",
      left: "90%",
      top: "center",
      feature: {
        mark: { show: true },
        magicType: { show: true, type: ["line", "bar"] },
      },
    },
    xAxis: [
      {
        type: "category",
        axisLine: { onZero: true },
        axisTick: { show: true, inside: true },
        data: Object.keys(data.analytics.min).map((val) => val),
        axisLabel: {
          inside: false,
          rotate: -25,
          hideOverlap: true,
          truncate: false,
          fontSize: 10,
          nameTruncate: { maxWidth: 5, ellipsis: "..." },
        },
      },
    ],
    yAxis: [
      {
        type: "value",
      },
    ],
    series: [
      {
        name: "min",
        type: "line",
        itemStyle: {
          color: colors.min,
        },
        emphasis: {
          focus: "series",
        },
        areaStyle: {
          color: new graphic.LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 1, [
            {
              offset: 0,
              color: colors.areaTop,
            },
            {
              offset: 1,
              color: colors.areaBase,
            },
          ]),
        },
        data: data.analytics ? Object.values(data.analytics.min) : [],
      },
      {
        name: "mean",
        type: "line",
        label: "Mean",
        itemStyle: {
          color: colors.mean,
        },
        emphasis: {
          focus: "series",
        },

        areaStyle: {
          color: new graphic.LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 1, [
            {
              offset: 0,
              color: colors.areaTop,
            },
            {
              offset: 1,
              color: colors.areaBase,
            },
          ]),
        },
        data: data.analytics ? Object.values(data.analytics.mean) : [],
      },
      {
        name: "max",
        type: "line",
        itemStyle: {
          color: colors.max,
        },
        emphasis: {
          focus: "series",
        },
        areaStyle: {
          color: new graphic.LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 1, [
            {
              offset: 0,
              color: colors.areaTop,
            },
            {
              offset: 1,
              color: colors.areaBase,
            },
          ]),
        },
        data: data.analytics ? Object.values(data.analytics.max) : [],
      },
    ],
  };
  return <ReactEChart option={barOptions} className={"morale-bar-chart"} />;
}
```

Comment: Set `boundaryGap: false` for the `xAxis`, see the [docs](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.boundaryGap).

Comment: Thank you! Yes this solved the issue I was having.  Somehow out of all the things I tried I must have missed that one.  Thank you again @kikon

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the issue I was having was solved by the answer given in a comment by @kikon.  He pointed me to the boundaryGap option and provided a link to the [Echart docs](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.boundaryGap).  Setting that to false did the trick, a 5 second fix. Thanks again @kikon!